# Making a tool out of commands

Tags: scripting

I'm softimage user. In softimage you can take some commands that you would frequently use and turn them to a custom tool. I'm wonder if I can do the same thing in blender

Comment: Welcome to Blender.StackExchange! Yes, Blender allows the use of python to create custom tools. While I myself am not proficient in Blender's usage of Python, hopefully someone else can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some ways to make custom macro buttons or a panel of operators that you define yourself. In the Scripting editor, there is an option to look at the python script templates that ship with blender - there is one that is called Simple Operator. If you have already seen some of the videos on Youtube or elsewhere about scripting in python in blender, then you might be familiar enough to follow a tutorial and copy the commands you want to reproduce into the Simple Operator script template and rename it to a specific name of your own.
example for simple panel with operator https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEkrQGFqM10
More info on the ways to take advantage of the python in the interface
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFoh3S8MLBI